# Custom forum installing mods

Tags: php, forum

I will build a custom forum and at the end it has to be easly customized like installing mods styles etc, the style template it;s easy to do but mods..? We all know how phpbb mods work you will have to edit lots of files but not the same for vbulletin or ipboard where mods are installed from 1 click.. how they did it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extensions for well-written web applications are typically architected around the concept of *hooks* — the core application defines a set of locations at which an extension can be triggered to potentially modify the application's behavior or data surrounding the call to the hook.

Two open-source web applications which use this architecture are WordPress and MediaWiki.

Comment: Thank you sir i really had no idea what and where to start looking for.